# how to initialize an empty date variable

Tags: php, date

I need to select a specific date meeting certain conditions from a database, i declared the date as $ldate="" and diplay the selected date on screen, but the result always shows 01 jan 1970. pls help.

```
    $ldate="";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $lamt=$row['Loan_Amount'];
                $today=time();
                if(empty(strtotime($row['loan_date1']))){
                $timespan=(time()-strtotime($row['Loan_Date']))/(60*60*24);
                $month=round($timespan/31); 
                $ldate=$row['Loan_Date'];}

                if(strtotime($row['loan_date1'])>0 and empty(strtotime($row['loan_date2']))){
                $timespan=(time()-strtotime($row['loan_date1']))/(60*60*24);
                $month=round($timespan/31);
                $ldate=$row['loan_date1'];      }

                Print '<td align="center" style="width:100px;">'.date("d M Y",strtotime($ldate)). "</td>";
```

Comment: declare  $ldate= "" outside of the while loop

Comment: i tried, all goes well in my laptop, but when uploaded in server in shows 1 jan 1970

Comment: Where exactly are you setting `$ldate=""` in that code?

Comment: Please format your code. This is hardly readable. If date returns the epoch, then $ldate does not contain a parsable date.

Comment: just above while loop

Answer (score 0):

You're giving an empty string to a date formatter function. It handles this as being *uninitialized* and creates the standard UNIX start date to display: https://3v4l.org/uYfnZ

You can put a check around the `.date` function in your Print function. If the variable is empty, just print an empty string:

```
if (empty($date)) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo date("Y M d", strtotime($date));
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the date field in database is always filled up

Comment: That may be, but you're somehow still giving the `.date()` function an empty string. Try to debug your code or put some print statements in it to check the value of `$ldate` in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Solved
instead of  using empty(strtotime($row['loan_date1'])) i used
$row['loan_date1']==0,  and it worked worked